# How to correctly use FETCH FIRST in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I was trying to find out how to only select the first element of the SELECT query.

It seems alot of people use LIMIT 1 to only select the first one, but that doesn't seem like the best way to do it.

I was reading up on SELECT in the Postgresql docs, and it seems there is an option for a FETCH statement but I can't find any examples online, could someone explain to me how to correctly use it?

Comment: If you need example - its [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-fetch.html). But if you need just a first row(s) from the query then using `limit` is the best way (in most cases).

Comment: @Abelisto best? it's the old non-standard way to do it.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The following statements are equivalent:

```
SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 10;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM foo FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

`ROWS` is interchangeable with `ROW`, which makes fetching just 1 a little more grammatically consistent.

`FETCH FIRST X ROWS ONLY` is part of the SQL standard, while, to my recollection, `LIMIT` is not. `LIMIT` is very popular, and much more terse, so it is also supported by postgres.

**Edited to add**: The two statements are only syntactically different. They generate exactly the same plans:

```
=# explain select * from foo fetch first 10 row only;
                         QUERY PLAN                          
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..0.22 rows=10 width=68)
   ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..18.50 rows=850 width=68)

=# explain select * from foo limit 10;
                         QUERY PLAN                          
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..0.22 rows=10 width=68)
   ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..18.50 rows=850 width=68)
```

Comment: And performance wise, those two are the same? They just do the same thing but different wording

Comment: Yep, identical. Purely a syntactic difference. I've posted the identical explain plans (for my simple query and small test table) above.

Comment: Try to perform test on table with multiple rows, I think Seq scan chosen by DB because of small records count

Comment: Why do these two syntaxes exist?

Comment: One is the SQL standard, the other is a popular but nonstandard extension. The latter didn't originate with postgres, but they supported it eventually.